# Como converter java.util.Date para java.sql.Date mantendo-se horas, minutos e segundos?

Tags: java, jdbc

Estou fazendo um programinha em Java. Nele eu recebo uma data do tipo `java.util.Date`, porém preciso dele em `java.sql.Date` para que possa inserir no banco de dados. Mas, nessa data, eu tenho hora, minuto e segundo e eu gostaria de inserir com todos esses dados. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para converter de `java.util.Date` para `java.sql.Date`:

```
java.util.Date a = ...;
java.sql.Date b = new java.sql.Date(a.getTime());
```

Para inserir com data e hora, utilize a [classe `java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html):

```
java.util.Date a = ...;
java.sql.Timestamp b = new java.sql.Timestamp(a.getTime());
```

Você pode utilizar um `Timestamp` com um `PreparedStatement` no [método `setTimestamp(int, Timestamp)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp-int-java.sql.Timestamp-). Para obter um desses de um `ResultSet`, utilize o [método `getTimestamp(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp-int-) ou o [método `getTimestamp(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Perfeito cara, resolveu meu problema! Muito obrigado